# Any c++ string library like QString (or Java String)?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm working on a windows program using MFC, currently I use std::string and std::wstring, the problems are I have to convert them from each other and handle encoding everywhere.

The QString API looks very decent, it can handle those problems just in one class, so my questions are:

1. Can I use only QString without depending on whole QT library?
2. Is there alternatives (A class handling both char and wchar, encoding, etc.)

Comment: You'll have to use QtCore to be able to use QString. That's the smallest library that I think can be built that has no other Qt dependencies.

Comment: I hope you already considered using the CString class which is already there in MFC.

Comment: @dorKKnight Seems that CString also has CStringA and CStringW underlying

Comment: Always use wide strings.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis How to always use? 1) std::exception does not accept std::wstring, 2) Some library uses std::string. 3) Even winapi like GetProcAddress uses char* not wchar_t*

Comment: @user1633272 GetProcAddress is a totally minor (0,000001%) of the APIs that have only a non wide version - and that is for a reason. For stuff that you would need a std::string, you can create a class that normally uses wstring and converts to string on demand using `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, GetProcAddress is trivial indeed, and I'm already using WideCharToMultiByte, the thing is I have a lot of places need to do conversion   for exception message, or format a log with exception.what()

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I can deal with std::string <=> std::wstring conversion already, what I'm looking for is a simpler way to do it, e.g. QString could helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Can I use only QString without depending on whole QT library? Yes you can.
   You havn't to use other Qt libraries.
2. QString has a lot useful functions to convert the QString into a other type, like:

```
    std::wstring wString;
    wString = 'w';
    QString qString = QString::fromStdWString(wString);
    std::string sString = qString.toStdString();
    const char * cP = sString.c_str();
    qString = cP;
    wString = qString.toStdWString();
```

Answer (score 1):

MFC has its own implementation of the string class: CString
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring?view=vs-2019